# How to calculate this integral involving the screened Coulomb potential?

Tags: integration, physics

For my physics class I have to calculate the following integral:

$$
\frac{\text{d}\sigma}{\text{d}\omega}=|f(\vec{k}, \vec{k'})|^2
$$

where

$$
f(\vec{k}, \vec{k'})=-\frac{m}{2\pi \hbar^2} \int e^{i(\vec{k}, \vec{k'})\cdot \vec{r}}\cdot V(\vec{r})\text{d}^3r
$$

and

$$
V(r)=\frac{qQ}{4\pi\epsilon_r \epsilon_0 r}e^{-r/\lambda_D}
$$

The result should be

$$
\frac{\text{d}\sigma}{\text{d}\omega}=\left(\frac{2mqQ}{\hbar^24\pi\epsilon_r\epsilon_0}\right)^2 \frac{1}{(2k^2(1-\cos\theta)+\lambda_D^{-2})^2}
$$

So far I have rearranged the integrals to

$$
\frac{\text{d}\sigma}{\text{d}\omega}=C \cdot \int e^{i \cdot \Delta \vec{k} \cdot \vec{r}} \cdot e^{-r/\lambda_D}\cdot \frac{1}{r}\text{d}^3r \cdot \int e^{-i \cdot \Delta \vec{k} \cdot \vec{r}} \cdot e^{-r/\lambda_D}\cdot \frac{1}{r}\text{d}^3r
$$

with

$$
C=\frac{m^2q^2Q^2}{64\pi^4\hbar^4\epsilon_0^2\epsilon_r^2}
$$

Can anyone tell me how I can get to the solution?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: your omega is a solid angle? This what your calculating is the cross section?

Comment: This is not the coulomb potential. It has a $e^{-r}$ term.

Comment: theta is the angle with respect to what?

Comment: This looks more to the Yukawa potential $V(r) = -g^2e^{-kmr}(1/r)$ and I suspect that $(\vec{k},\vec{k'}) = \vec{k} - \vec{k'},$

Comment: Go to polar coordinates with vector $\vec k - \vec k '$ playing the role of $z$ axis. The integration over $\phi$ gives a factor of $2 \pi$ and the integral over $\theta$ is done by substitution $x= \cos \theta$. What remains is radial integral which should be possible to do with residue calculus.